# EXCEL VBA - Webquery: webpage redirection

Tags: excel, vba

So I have the following problem: I try to make a webquery that will take the data from one website, but the problem is that this webpage is redirecting to another one when you first try to go that page. And the link will open only on the second try (without redirection).

What do i need to add in the code so i could get rid of the redirection problem? add a loop?

here's the code:

```
Sub Auto_open()

Dim newcon as String

Cells.Select
Selection.QueryTable.Delete
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
newcon = "an URL"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" + newcon _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "2"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling redirections

> .WebDisableRedirections = True

If that doesn't work try refreashing the query after a few seconds

`Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
.Refresh`

If that doesn't work you my want to consider using a Webbrowser Control.

Can you provide the url link for testing?

Comment: unfotunately i cant share with the link cause it requires to log in and only our employers have an access to this webpage. I have tried both methods and it still doesnt work. @thomasinzina